# Download Google App Engine Project

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've gotten appcfg.py to run. However, when I run the command it doesn't actually download the files. Nothing appears in the destination directory. 
There was a mixup and a lot of work got lost and the only way to recover them is to download them from the host.

```
python appcfg.py download_app -A beatemup-1097  /home/chaserlewis/Desktop/gcloud
```

The output is

```
Host: appengine.google.com
Fetching file list...
Fetching files...
```

Then it just returns without having downloaded anything. It is definitely hosted so I'm not sure what else to do.

I am doing this from a different computer then I deployed from if that matters. I couldn't get appcfg.py to run on my Windows machine unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

It might be due to the omitted version flag. Try the following:

1. Go to the [App Engine versions page](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions) in the console and check the version of your app that is serving traffic. If you don't specify the `-V` flag, the `appcfg` command will try to download the default version, which isn't necessarily your latest version or the version serving traffic.
2. Add the `-V` flag to your command with the target version that you identified from the console.

   ```
   python appcfg.py download_app -A beatemup-1097 -V [YOUR_VERSION]  /home/chaserlewis/Desktop/gcloud
   ```

Comment: didnt work for me, just says fetching files. i've included the `-V` flag and the projectId is correct too. Really not sure what else to try, any ideas/